# An example of an entire function, which is not polynomial, that has only one zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I cannot find an example of an entire function $f$ (i.e. $f: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$), which is not polynomial, that has only one zero. Besides these two, I had to find examples with no zeros and infinitely many, but I found them.

Comment: Do you know a non-polynomial entire function with no zero ? A polynomial with only one zero ? The product of both ?

Comment: I took $f(z)=z$ as a polynomial with only one zero and $e^z$ as non-polynomial with no zero? But the product is still polynomial..

Comment: @variableXYZ On what basis would you call $ze^z$ a polynomial?

Comment: @variableXYZ $ze^z$ is not a polynomial..it is a pointwise limit of a sequence of polynomials though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb C&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\z&\mapsto&ze^z.\end{array}$$